# Adding model to collection with index

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

while reading docs of backbone i can't understand how to add model to collection with option `{at: index}` and then get this model using 
    `mycollection.at('index')`?
When im doing 
    `myCollection.add(myModel, {at: myindex});`
then 
    `myCollection.at(myindex)`
returns `undefined`;

Comment: Most probably values for `myindex` are different in one and another place. If not, you're wrong with `Collection.add` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've said, it could be that your collection just isn't that long enough and your `myCollection.add(myModel, {at: myindex})` isn't able to splice it in.

Some demo code to replicate your problem:

```
// This is all done in the console

ships = new Backbone.Collection;
ship = new Backbone.Model;

ships.add(ship, {at:100});
myCollection.at(100);    // undefined
myCollection.at(0);      // model found
```

Maybe some sample code if this doesn't describe the issue?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think that i solved issue. The problem was that i tried to set index as string , like myCollection.add(myModel, {at: 'stringIndex'});

Comment: Heh heh. I guess that would do it!